# Facebook Login 'invalid version specified' (Bug? Or am I being stupid?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

Any help with this issue would be appreciated!

I'm getting this error in the console:

Uncaught b {message: 'invalid version specified', innerError: undefined}

As far as I'm aware 15.0 is the latest version, right? Here's my script which caused the error:

```
`<script>

FB.init({
appId      : 'myappidisherebuthidden',
status     : true,
xfbml      : true,
version    : 'v15.0'
});

(function(d, s, id){
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}  (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>`
```

I'm using the snippet from Facebook's quick start and it's not working. I'm about to go insane.
All answers given on questions I've seen so far don't seem to work either.

I've used the snippet given by FB, as well as attempting removing the 'v' from version

Snippet Facebook provides:

```
    <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
    appId            : 'your-app-id',
    autoLogAppEvents : true,
    xfbml            : true,
    version          : 'v15.0'
    });
    };
    </script>
    <script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" 
    src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js">    
    </script>`
```

Comment: did you try with an older version?

Comment: I've tried several versions but ended up with the same result. (2.5, 2.6, 9.0, 11.0, etc)

Comment: Don't worry, I have the IQ of a grilled cheese sandwich. I was editing the wrong file.

Comment: well...that's life for a programmer, i feel you :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok the answer is I'm stupid. I forgot I had duped the file to move into my htdocs folder. It turns out I was editing the wrong file and I've just wasted 2hrs of my life.

SMH

edit: If you're struggling with the 'Invalid version specified' problem refer to my code above and make sure you're editing the wrong file.